# If conditions are never satisfied (even though they are)

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I wrote an `if` statement followed by an `else` statement. Now even if the conditions are satisfied, it will just go to the `else` statement.

I've tried using `Objects.equal()` but that's not really what I want since I'm using `>=` signs instead of `==` signs, it also gives me errors and basically the whole program doesn't work. I also tried putting all conditions to the default values so I can be sure that they are satisfied but still nothing.

This is the function that contains the `if` statement.

```
function evolve() {
            if (coins >= 1000000000 && timesbuyj1 >= 10 && timesbuyj2 >= 10 && timesbuyj3 >= 10) {
                evolutions = evolutions += 1
                var coins = 0
                var timesbuyj1 = 0
                var price01cs = 15
                var timesbuyj2 = 0
                var price1cs = 100
                var timesbuyj3 = 0
                var price8cs = 1100
                var timesbuyj4 = 0
                // a bunch of lines of code that doesn't concern this here //
            } else {
                alert("You don't meet the requirements.")
            }
        }
```

When I change the values to satisfy the conditions, I expect everything to reset, change, etc.. But it just gives tells me `You don't meet the requirements.` and doesn't run the code it's supposed to run.

Comment: Why do you check variables before initializing them?

Comment: Can you "alert" the values if those 4 variables? What *are* really those values?

Comment: have you declared these variables before the function call? If you have, pass them to the function. That'll do it.

Comment: Your code as written simply makes no sense.    You are testing variables that are declared `var` inside the `if` block (and are therefore "hoisted" to the top of the scope) but the assignment of values to those variables doesn't happen unless the `if` branch is taken, which it never is.

Comment: Nik, the variables actually existed before this but I put them here to reset them to their default values. DEVCNN, yep, I have already declared the variables and am just resetting them in this function, what does "pass them to the function" mean? I thought I was doing that. Hans, yes I am able to use ```alert()``` on the values, they are just values for coins, and the amount of time the player bought something. Alnitak, as I said to other people, I have already declared these variables and am just resetting them to their default values.

Comment: Declared where?  You're certainly _not_ passing them to the function, which is not taking _any_ formal parameters.

Comment: Form the code shown here, each of the used variables is `undefined` because they are only initialized within the a part of the source, which can never be reached, while the variables are not initializied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are experiencing is variable hoisting, because of your declaration with `var` inside the if. That means, your variables are not what you think they are, but `undefined` - even though you declared them outside of the function. Simple example:

```js
var bar = "foo";

function foo() {
  console.log(bar); // undefined
  if (bar === undefined) { // true, even though you've declared it outside the function; but overriden from var bar = "bar"; inside the if
    alert('hoisting');
    var bar = "bar";
  } else {
    alert('never happens');
  }
}

function baz() {
  console.log(bar);
  if (bar === undefined) { // false, bar was not overriden and still has its value from outside the value
    alert('never happens');
    bar = undefined;
  } else {
    bar = "bar";
    alert(bar);
  }
}

foo();
baz();
```

To get the desired behavior, don't double declare your variables with `var`, just reassign their value

Wrong:

```
var coins = 0
```

Right:

```
coins = 0;
```

If you were to manually "hoist" the varibales in foo, you'd write the equivalent like this - that's how your code is interpreted right now

```js
var bar = "bar";

function foo() {
  var bar;
  console.log(bar);
  if (bar === undefined) { // true, even though you've declared it outside the function; but overriden from var bar = "bar"; inside the if
    alert('hoisting');
    bar = "bar";
  } else {
    alert('never happens');
  }
}

foo()
```

Either way, consider to actually pass the values to the function that checks the values, instead of relying on variables declared globally.